# autocomplete input show value even value is empty

Tags: input, autocomplete

I have input with autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm isFieldValueEmpty tooltip" 
style="width:779px;" id="searchK" name="keywords" value=''>
```

Everything works good, but I set value of autocomplete and after that add value from autocomplete to hidden input (user can choose many value from autocomplete). But when I add this value and try to set empty value of autocomplete input:

```
$("#searchK").attr("value","");
```

In input field still have text, but value od this input is empty (checking by firebug).

Any idea how delete this text?

**I found solution**

```
 $(this).val(''); 
    return false;
```

**And input is clear.**

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: I have it in two files and data from database, so it not simpty to post it there.

Comment: What are you using for your autocomplete? jQueryUI, bootstrap, etc.?

Comment: Bootstrap and jQueryUI

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `attr()` to change the value, use `val()`

```
$("#searchK").val("");
```

Comment: I try with val and attr, and any nothing change, I have still text in input (but value is empty).